# Tracking post type in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is there an easy way to filter between posts and pages in Google Analytics?

Page is listed as a Primary Dimension when I drill down to Content but I'm not sure if that includes posts as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not tracked by default.

Yoast's WordPress SEO plugin allows you to track post types (and categories and authors...) as a custom variable.

Comment: I guess I'm stuck at what Custom Variable (Key 1) would be

Comment: If I understand your question right, and you're trying to write your own custom variable, you want `get_post_type()`.

Comment: My question revolves around filtering posts and pages. Sure, the Yoast plugin will track post type as a custom variable, but the arguments for a custom variable are: gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', $slotNumber, $Category, $Value, $ScopeLevel ]); . Therefore, if I'm running a filter in Google Analytics based on the custom variable, what is the $Category I'm looking for? I would imagine it's something like "post_type" but I don't see any documentation on this.

Comment: The category is post_type. In the report, it's found in Audience > Demographics > Custom Variables.

Comment: Didn't see that, thanks! It's a shame you can't drill down from post_type to see what the actual page was.

Answer (score 2):

Page in Google Analytics is simply the webpage. You can do a search for your category slug to drill down posts and post categories. That's how I do it.